# Postgres HashAggregate running slow

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

The query below is running on a very large table (300MM rows) and is taking just under half a second to run.

```
SELECT  ld.user_profile_id,
        CASE WHEN ld.first_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE UPPER(first_name) END as first_name,
        CASE WHEN ld.last_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE UPPER(ld.last_name) END as last_name
FROM data ld
WHERE ld.hashed_ssn = 'xxxx'

UNION

SELECT  ld.user_profile_id,
        CASE WHEN ld.first_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE UPPER(first_name) END as first_name,
        CASE WHEN ld.last_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE UPPER(ld.last_name) END as last_name
FROM data ld
WHERE ld.email = '123@GMAIL.COM'

UNION

SELECT  ld.user_profile_id,
        CASE WHEN ld.first_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE UPPER(first_name) END as first_name,
        CASE WHEN ld.last_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE UPPER(ld.last_name) END as last_name
FROM data ld
WHERE ld.home_phone = '5512345678';
```

Below is the execution plan:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=11774.31..11802.68 rows=2837 width=110) (actual time=404.978..405.003 rows=12 loops=1)
"  Group Key: ld.user_profile_id, (CASE WHEN (ld.first_name IS NULL) THEN ''::text ELSE upper((ld.first_name)::text) END), (CASE WHEN (ld.last_name IS NULL) THEN ''::text ELSE upper((ld.last_name)::text) END)"
  ->  Append  (cost=0.70..11696.29 rows=2837 width=110) (actual time=3.935..402.438 rows=1131 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using hashed_ssn_index_data on data ld  (cost=0.70..4425.12 rows=1074 width=110) (actual time=3.935..353.560 rows=376 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((hashed_ssn)::text = 'XXXX'::text)
        ->  Index Scan using email_index_data on data ld_1  (cost=0.57..3349.39 rows=814 width=110) (actual time=3.834..30.938 rows=379 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((email)::text = '123@GMAIL.COM'::text)
        ->  Index Scan using home_phone_index_data on data ld_2  (cost=0.57..3893.41 rows=949 width=110) (actual time=3.429..17.663 rows=376 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((home_phone)::text = '55512345678'::text)
Planning time: 55.073 ms
Execution time: 405.311 ms
```

I did add indexes to hashed_ssn, email and phone, however I'm still not getting the speed that I'm looking for. Is this just because the table is so large? Any suggestions on how to speed up this query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could win some by squeezing out the three domains (ld.hashed_ssn,ld.email,ld.home_phone), and refer to them by a (surrogate) FK, especially if their cardinality isl ower than the number of rows in your table.

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving about 400 rows, which are randomly located on the disk. This requires maybe about 1000 IO operations, and its speed will depend on how many IOPS can your storage provide.

If your table does not change very often you can force it to store data rows of the same `hashed_ssn` close to each other. This way the query will not have to retrieve that many random blocks from storage.

```
alter table data cluster on hashed_ssn_index_data;
cluster data;
```

This would take quite a lot of time and will block the table even for reads. The database would not try to preserve this order or rows on inserts/updates, so if you will be changing your data, performance will gradually decrease. But you can rerun `cluster data;` periodically.

Comment: The table changes very often. I'm adding about 600K rows per day. I could set up a weekly job on the weekends to 'cluster data.'' However, given that it's changing so often do you believe it would still be beneficial to cluster?

Comment: Adding more RAM would also help.

Comment: A weekly or even monthly job to cluster this data will be quite beneficial. But the question is whether you can afford required downtime. The first one will be slower than subsequent ones. There's a [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) extension that can do this without downtime, but even slower.